# What's wrong with this vigenere cs50 code?

Tags: c, algorithm, vigenere, cs50

It just isn't working. Can you point out what's wrong? When I run it I get:

```
jharvard@appliance (~/Dropbox/pset2): ./vigenere bacon
Meet me at the park
ARTU [R \T aW` ^NaL
```

Which is clearly wrong. I've spent countless hours on this. here is code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc,string argv[])
{
    if(argc!=2)
    {
    printf("Usage: /home/cs50/pset2/caesar <key>\n");
    return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        char *k = argv[1];
        string p = GetString();
        int klen = strlen(k);

        for(int i=0; i<klen;i++)
        {
            if(isupper(k[i]))
            {
                k[i] = k[i]-65;
            }
            else if (islower(k[i]))
            {
                k[i] = k[i]-97;
            }

        }

        for(int i=0, n=strlen(p); i<n;i++)
        {

                if(isupper(p[i]))
                {
                    printf("%c", (((p[i]-65)+(k[i%klen]-65))%26)+65);
                }
                else if (islower(p[i]))
                {
                    printf("%c", (((p[i]-97)+(k[i%klen])-97)%26)+97);
                }

                else
                {
                   printf("%c", p[i]);
                }

        }
        printf("\n");

    }
}
```

Comment: What is `string`? What does `GetString` do?

Comment: `for(int i=0, n=strlen(p); i<n;i++)` this looks suspicious. What does `GetString()` do?

Comment: Also, you transform the "key" array `k` to be numbers instead of ASCII values, but then you still subtract from `k[...]` in the second loop, giving you very wrong values.

Comment: @Joachim @FilipeGetString() receives a string from a user. It is in the cs50 library. If the user inputs a non-string then it prints "Retry()"

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `typedef char *string;` , and `char *GetString() /* get line from stdin and return pointer to malloc'd space */`  (I know this from previously posted questions with the same stuff)

Comment: In `(((p[i]-65)+(k[i%klen]-65))%26)+65);` you probably want to take out the second `-65`.  Also, replace `65` with `'A'` and `97` with `'a'`, it will make your code easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in comments, the code for the loop over `p` should be :

EDIT per comment : code is adapted to skip non alpha charactes

```
int j = 0
for(int i=0, n=strlen(p); i<n;i++)
{

        if(isupper(p[i]))
        {
            printf("%c", (((p[i]-65)+(k[j%klen]))%26)+65);
            j += 1
        }
        else if (islower(p[i]))
        {
            printf("%c", (((p[i]-97)+(k[j%klen]))%26)+97);
            j += 1
        }

        else
        {
           printf("%c", p[i]);
        }
}
```

And the output for `./vigenere bacon` with `Meet me at the park` should be :

```
Negh zf av huf pcfx
```

Comment: The output should actually be 'Negh zf av huf pcfx'..
What I want to do is this:
Meet me at the park ->
baco nb ac onb acon ->
Negh zf av huf pcfx
..
The place of index of b which is 1 (a=0) is substracted from the index of M.

Comment: Actually, the spaces in the message is not being ignored. How do I ignore the spaces?

Comment: @rohan : I was using `Meet me at the park -> baconbaconbaconbaco`. I'll edit my answer to skip non alphabetic characters (here spaces).

Comment: btw, I understand that I was not able to get this problem right because of lack of logic reasoning, right? Is there a way to develop this ability and solve these type of problems in future without asking for help? Or am I just not born to be a programmer?

Comment: @rohan The good rule is to keep away from the keyboard until the logic is clear. Paper and pencil are still good for this phase :-). And stepping through a debugger can help to understand at what moment things become wrong ... Good luck anyway